# Get nearest index value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

so in order to restrict my app's user sql login I turned off create, drop, index, alter, tmp and lock. So, one of my tables will have rows deleted by the users, hence the index will most likely have a bunch of gaps, some being very large. I would just make the user re-index the table after a delete, but that would require me to enable drop and/or alter, which for security reasons I do not want to enable.

So now the user wants to access the index number 50 from this table but there's a gap from 48-54 for instance. How would I go about this?

Comment: The database engine will handle index maintenance in the name of the user. So even if the user doesn't have `drop index` rights, the integrity of the index is guaranteed.

Comment: Why would the user want to access id 50? An auto-incrementing id exists for the benefit of data integrity. It has no meaning beyond the scope of the database. A user need neither know nor care what the id associated with their desired row is! In a nutshell, don't worry about the gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select * from my_table where id > 48 order by id limit 1

Comment: I guess this would work, but I've changed my methods anyways. On the other hand I would be trying to access a random row, so the fastest method would be to take the highest id and lowest id and make a random number, which could be in a gap.